# Better way to handle exception is spring-boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception

I have some Ten API which talks to redis for storing the data.

Currently it is throwing nested exception, so I have done like below to handle the nested exception.

```
    @Override 
    public boolean delMyStatus(String key) {
        try{
            return  redisTemplate.delete(key);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            if(e.getCause() != null && e.getCause().getCause() instanceof RedisException) {     
                RedisException ex = (RedisException)e.getCause().getCause();
                log.error("RedisException  " + ex.getMessage());
/* Do some action*/
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException("...");
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But I dont want to do this for all the APIS of redis dao, Is there any better way to handle exception.

Comment: `catch (RedisException e){}`?

Comment: catch (RedisException e){
log.error("RedisException  " + ex.getMessage());
         } 

catch (Exception e){
log.error("Exception  " + ex.getMessage());
         } 
 This is always going to Exception block

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@RestControllerAdvice`. Make a custom exception class `CustomRedisException` throw `CustomRedisException` Exception from every controller and handle this in separate `class` annotated with `@RestControllerAdvice`.

```
@Override 
public boolean delMyStatus(String key) {
    try{
        return  redisTemplate.delete(key);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        if(e.getCause() != null && e.getCause().getCause() instanceof RedisException) {      RedisException ex = (RedisException)e.getCause().getCause();
           throw new CustomRedisException(ex);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("...");
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Make GlobalExceptionHandler like below.

```
@RestControllerAdvice(basePackages = "your base package here", basePackageClasses = RepositoryRestExceptionHandler.class)
public class GlobalRestExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleCustomException(final CustomRedisExceptionex) {

        // code for exception handling here.

        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.PRECONDITION_FAILED.value(), ex.getMessage()),
                HttpStatus.PRECONDITION_FAILED);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I dont want to return this error  to rest-controller, it was for some internal operation , so I want to handle this error internally and do some actions based on that

Comment: In this case, you can make a common method to handle the exception and call this from every catch block.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with aspects and `@AfterThrowing` annotation.

First make sure you allowed Spring to use aspects using `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` annotation on any of your configuration classes.

Then define an `@Aspect` class with method annotated with `@AfterThrowing` like this:

```
@Aspect
public class GenericExceptionHandler {

    // you can use more specific path here
    @AfterThrowing ("execution(* *.*(..))", throwing = "ex")
    public void handleException(Exception ex) throws Exception { 
          // handle the exception here
     }

}
```

Comment: In this I want to log some parameter sent by caller. So how to send the user parameter along with the exception  to @AfterThrowing function